# Declaring JavaScript variables in a HTML link

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a simple HTML document with the following:

```
<a href="results.html"> cake </a>
<a href="results.html"> pie </a>
```

and `results.html` contains a variable that needs to be declared in Javscript as 100 for the first link, 200 for the second, and so on.

Is there any way I can make it so that when you click on the first link, it opens `results.html` with a javascript variable set to cake, the second one opens `results.html` with the variable set to pie, and so on?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass them in the query string. For example:

```
<a href="results.html?result=cake"> cake </a>
<a href="results.html?result=pie"> pie </a>
```

In your results.html page you get and parse the query string. For example:

```
var queryStr = window.location.search.substring(1);
var params = parseQueryStr(queryStr);
console.log(params["result"]);

var parseQueryStr = function(queryStr) {
    var params = {};

    var queryArray = queryStr.split("&");

    for (var i = 0, var l = queryArray.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var temp = queryArray[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }

    return params;
};
```

Comment: using `location.hash` would be a lot easier in my opinion... Of course it won't be available on the server-side, but it doesn't look like the OP needs it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="results.html?keyword=cake"> cake </a>
<a href="results.html?keyword=pie"> pie </a>
```

In results.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getQueryParams(qs) {
        qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

        var params = {}, tokens,
            re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

        while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
            params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
                = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
        }

        return params;
    }

    var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
    alert(query.keyword);
</script>
```